# Has anyone pushed CrowdStrike Falcon sensor to a macOS-BigSur using Intune?

Tags: macos, bundle-identifier, intune, falcon

I have successfully pushed all the required profiles to my test mac that includes full disc access, script to assign license key, Kernel extensions. When I push the sensor, I get the following error in the Intune portal:"One or more apps contain invalid bundleIDs. (0x87D13BA2)".

If some has has successfully deployed CrowdStrike Falcon sensor version 6.x.x to MacOS BigSur, please share instructions.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs if your .pkg package doesn't contain the following information:

1. The package version and CFBundleVersion string in the packageinfo file.
2. The correct install-location in the pkg-info file.

Comment: Do you know how I can edit the .pkg.intunemac file add the CFBundleVersion String and correct install location within the packageinfo file. Not sure how to edit the packageinfo. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Asked developer to check the above field in the <pkg-info>.